How add reviewer to PR without adding them to collaborators
I want to add a reviewer to my Pull Request (PR) on a public repository without adding them as a collaborator. The issue is that GitHub only allows requesting reviews from users who are collaborators. Is there a workaround or a way to assign reviewers for PRs without granting them full collaborator access to the repository?
I tried adding a reviewer by manually typing their username in the PR review section, but GitHub only allowed me to choose from existing collaborators. I expected to be able to assign review requests to any GitHub user, regardless of their collaborator status. However, GitHub returned an error, requiring the user to be added as a collaborator first, which I want to avoid.

All LLMs say it's possible to do. Share your comments

LLM -> Large Library of Mistakes (just joking)

You can't, and not necessary.
Reviews from users without write permission won't affect the merging status of PRs. Their approvals looks like:

This is an approval from a user with write permission looks like:

And if you don't turn on Code review limits in settings page, a user explicitly granted access can voluntarily review PRs. So just ping them. If they are willing, they can add themselves to the reviewer list.

If you still want to do that, in organization-owned repositories, you can do that by grantting them read permission. Still adds to collaborators, but permissions haven't changed. Then they will be included in the candidate reviewer list.
